# Difference between Single-supply and Dual-supply CAN Transceiver

Tags: power-supply, can, bus, transceiver

I was about to choose the MCP2558FD CAN Transceiver for a personal project. I found on the [datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2304140030_Microchip-Tech-MCP2558FD-H-SN_C124015.pdf) the following diagram:

[image]

If my understanding is good, I can use it as a dual-supply Transceiver.

But I don't understand the physical difference on the CAN bus between single-supply and dual-supply.

What are the benefits and the disadvantages of both configurations ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CAN Bus transceiver \$V_{RXD}\$/\$V_{IO}\$ pin confusion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/666457/can-bus-transceiver-v-rxd-v-io-pin-confusion)

Comment: The picture you posted about internals of the transceiver is pretty useless to look at. Instead look at the typical applications part of the datasheet. After which it becomes _very_ obvious what the purpose of the extra supply pin is. Figure 1-2 and 1-3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

V<sub>DD</sub> is the 5V supply voltage of the IC.

MCP255**8**FD specific:
V<sub>IO</sub> is the power supply of the digital interface, which includes `TXD`, `RXD` and `S`.

If you want to connect the CAN transceiver to a MCU with a lower voltage rating than 5 V (eg 1.8 V, 3.3 V), you'll either need to level-shift the digital interface, or (more conveniently) use a CAN transceiver with an integrated separate power supply for the digital interface.

> But I don't understand the physical difference on the CAN bus between single-supply and dual-supply.

There is no difference on the CAN bus interface, since the CAN interface is powered by V<sub>DD</sub> (5 V) in both cases.

> What are the benefits and the disadvantages of both configurations?

If you're interfacing this IC to a 5 V MCU then you don't need the MCP255**8**FD variant. MCP255**7**FD is probably cheaper and just as good.

If you have to level-shift the digital interface to 1.8 V .. <5 V, I'd recommend the MCP255**8**FD variant, because you can then do without a separate level shifter.

Comment: So there is no advantage using a dual supply over a single supply ?

Comment: If you don't need the level-shifting capability, then there's no advantage using the dual-supply variant.

Comment: Thanks for your tips ! I don't like to work on something I don't understand ^^

Answer (score 2):

This device has a separate supply for the IO and CAN bus sections. It enables interfacing to low voltage (2.5 & 1.8V) MCUs, thus lowering the system power consumption.